# quantlib: make AmortizingFixedRateBond coupon payments equal

Tags: quantlib

I found some unexpected result when trying to call AmortizingFixedRateBond wiht daily coupon payments, but starting in the last day of the month.

```
settlementDays = 0
calendar = ql.Russia()
nominal = 1000
startDate = ql.Date(31, 8, 2021) #ql.Date.todaysDate() 
duration = ql.Period('12m')
frequency = ql.Monthly
interest = 0.07
daytimeConvention = ql.Thirty360()
businessAdjustment = ql.ModifiedFollowing

annuityAsBond = ql.AmortizingFixedRateBond(settlementDays, calendar, nominal, startDate, duration, frequency, interest, daytimeConvention, businessAdjustment, ql.Date())

leg = ql.Leg([*annuityAsBond.cashflows()])        
df = pd.DataFrame({'Date': [c.date().to_date() for c in leg],
                           'Payment': [c.amount() for c in leg]})
df = df.groupby('Date').sum()
```

Output:

```
             Payment
Date                
2021-09-30  86.526746
2021-10-29  86.526746
2021-11-30  86.526746
2021-12-31  86.526746
2022-01-31  86.526746
2022-02-28  **86.296602**
2022-03-31  **86.823502**
2022-04-29  86.526746
2022-05-31  86.526746
2022-06-30  86.526746
2022-07-29  86.526746
2022-08-31  86.526746
```

As you see, the annuity calculator breaks a little bit (basically it transfers a single day interest from one month to another due to shortness of the February). At the same time, it is totally working as expected if `startDate` is not the end of the month. I tried different combinations of the convention and businessAdjustment, but this end of month trick is persistent. Is there a way around it to obtain correct coupons?

Answer (score 1):

You should use the following day convention, but first construct your schedule using the issue date and the maturity date of the bond.

```python
schedule = ql.Schedule(issueDate, maturityDate, ql.Period(frequency), calendar, businessAdjustment, businessAdjustment, ql.DateGeneration.Backward, True)
dayConvention = ql.ActualActual(ql.ActualActual.ISMA, schedule)
```

Moreover, change your `annuityAsBond` to the following:

```python
annuityAsBond = ql.AmortizingFixedRateBond(settlementDays, [nominal], schedule, [interest], dayConvention, businessAdjustment)
```

Also, if it is an amortizing fixed rate bond, shouldn't there be more than one nominal? Else, it becomes a simple fixed rate bond.